# Is it possible to create a Windows 7 virtual machine on Ubuntu Server without GUI?

Tags: windows-7, windows, ubuntu, virtual-machine

I have a Ubuntu Server 12.04 server without GUI. Would it be possible to install Windows 7 (with GUI) as a virtual machine on the server? I want to use Windows 7 with remote desktop on my phone.

Comment: The guest machine doesn't care whether the host has a GUI or not.  But the initial installation (and any troubleshooting that may be necessary later) could be a problem.

Comment: An unattended install of Windows would circumvent the install problem. It's definitely possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to install this VM somewhere else or if you already have it, that's great. Otherwise will be difficult to install it without GUI.

And you can install and use [Xvfb server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xvfb) for your VM (which is X virtual framebuffer). It works like X window, but without GUI. In case of some issues with your Windows, you could also make some screenshots from your Xvfb and save into file and see them somewhere else.